# Remainder of large power of 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the remainder when 
$$3^{2^{2016}}-1$$  is divided by $2^{2019}$?

My thought was that we could split it up in 
$$\left( 3^{2^{2015}}-1 \right)\left( 3^{2^{2015}}+1 \right)$$ and then keep doing that until we get something like 
$$8 \prod_{k=1}^{2015} \left( 3^{2^{k}}+1 \right)$$

Well I see that each term is divisible by 2 at least once, and there's a $2^3$ left over so the whole thing is at least divisible by $2^{2018}$, but I'm not quite sure how to find it modulo $2^{2019}$?

**Note**
This is an old competition problem, but I unfortunately do not know the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Prove by induction that $3^{2^{n-3}} \equiv 1 + 2^{n-1} \bmod 2^n$ for $n \ge 4$.

(This implies that $3$ has order $2^{n-2}$ mod $2^n$, the largest possible order.)

Comment: How could I suspect this myself?

Comment: @Sky, by trying a few examples with small $n$. I knew that from the structure of $U(2^n)$, hence my remark in the last sentence.

Comment: @Sky, or you could expand $3^{2^k}=(1+2)^{2^k}$ using the binomial theorem.